# how to move "div.s4-title s4-lp" tag to above the blue ribbon in v4.master?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am new to SharePoint and am trying to brand my team site according to a youtube video:
"Awesome SharePoint 2010 Home Page Within 30 minutes part 2/3 " -->
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kqo91Gc7Wtc

I was able to select "div.s4-title s4-lp" tag but cannot see exactly where the author is moving the selected tag to in v4.master.

when I try to move anywhere above the ribbon on my master page, the preview doesn't look right on SharePoint designer

So I am looking for guidance on where in the master page should I "cut and past" the selected tag?

thanks in advance for any help in this matter

Comment: Why would you want to move anything above the ribbon? Just a note: The ribbon should always be on top and working around that will create more complications for you than benefits.